# Differences between various official Microsoft Windows .iso files

Tags: windows-7, windows, iso-image, windows-installation

I want to make a bootable USB thumb drive to install Windows on my computer. I don't want to use my old DVD to create an image and then upgrade to SP1, so I decided to download an untouched .iso file that already has SP1 in it. My question is this, is there a difference between these two files files?

> en_windows_7_home_premium_with_sp1_x64_dvd_620851.iso

vs

> en_windows_7_home_premium_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_676549.iso

What does `dvd_u` mean, is it somehow different from plain `dvd`? Also will these work with my retail Home Premium key or do these work only for thoe with TechNet/MSDN accounts?

Comment: Your retail (or upgrade, or OEM, etc.) key will work fine with these ISOs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the u version is more recent according to this site
[check this for details](http://www.mydigitallife.info/get-windows-7-sp1-u-media-refresh-msdntechnet-iso-download-or-convert/)

Answer (score 7):

U means it is updated with this hotfix, as per reading the link provided by daya

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2534111

[image]