# What's the difference between these Windows versions?

Tags: windows-7, iso-image

I need a Windows 7 installation file (ISO image). Microsoft <s>no longer provides</s> doesn't provide those for customers with an OEM installation (customer care!), but I found them on [mirror.corenoc.de](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/). These seem to be the originals from Microsoft, without keys, so you can't use them if you don't already have a key. (I just want to stress that this seems legal to me.)

On that site I find several version with similar names, apart from an added "u" in the name, like

> en_windows_7_home_premium_with_sp1_x64_dvd_620851.iso
>
> en_windows_7_home_premium_with_sp1_x64_dvd_u_676549.iso

Does anyone know what's the difference between the ones with the "u" and the ones without?

Comment: @Mokubai Sorry should have included this:
http://superuser.com/questions/377623/differences-between-various-official-microsoft-windows-iso-files